# Python Audio Edit

Tags: python, audio, edit, editing

I am searching for a way to write a simple python
program to perform an automatic edit on an audio file.

I wrote with PIL automatic picture resizing to a predefined size.
I would like to write the same for automatic file re-encoding into a predefined bitrate.

similarly, i would like to write a python program that can stretch an audio file and re-encode it.

do i have to parse MP3's by myself, or is there a library that can be used for this?

Comment: If you want to _stretch_ and do other audio effects that aren't typical operations users would perform to their audio, you might have better luck using `ffmpeg` to convert from mp3 or whatever input format to [pcm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCM), play around with the audio yourself, and then use `ffmpeg` or similar tools to re-encode into whatever output format you want.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than doing this natively in Python, I strongly recommend leaving the heavy lifting up to FFMPEG, by executing it from your script.

It can chop, encode, and decode just about anything you throw at it.  You can find a list of common parameters here:  http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/

This way, you can leave your Python program to figure out the logic of what you want to cut and where, and not spend a decade writing code to deal with all of the audio formats available.

If you don't like the idea of directly executing it, there is also a [Python wrapper available for FFMPEG](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/).

Answer (score 0):

There is [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub). It's an easy to use library.